# Meaning of "Material career"

Tags: meaning

> The only events worth noting in his **material career** are his
>   installation at Toulouse at the age of 30 (14 May 1631), as
>   commissioner of requests;
>
> from Eric Temple Bell's *Men of Mathematics*

The sentence is about Fermat (A mathematician). Does material career mean "Non-Spiritual" , "Non-Mathematics" or "earthly" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To quote one of the many definitions for **material** from Chambers,

> Relating to subject matter

We need the [right context](http://www.math.rutgers.edu/~cherlin/History/Papers2000/pellegrino.html) here. Fermat was a student of law and had a degree in civil law. But today the world does not remember him for his contributions to law. The *material* in the sentence pertains to the subject of law. The only notable event in his legal career was his becoming the commissioner of requests.

Comment: This sounds right to me. I'm not familiar with OP's usage, but I'd guess *material* is by way of contrast with *immaterial = not relevant*. Fermat presumably did lots of things, but the only ones we remember and care about today are his contributions to mathematics.